# 4K display won't connect to Ubuntu 22.04 using Thunderbolt/usbc cable. Lenovo X1 Carbon 6th gen

Tags: ubuntu, xrandr

Have a monitor that occasionally correctly connects to my X1 Carbon. It's 4K 100hz display. Using HDMI keeps it at 50hz which is trash. I am using a top end cable thunderbolt cable that works for all my other monitors/computers.

When it does (sometimes) connect, everything is buttery smooth.

Here is the output from dmesg when it doesn't work:

```
  98.614725] usb 4-1: new SuperSpeed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[   98.634495] usb 4-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0451, idProduct=8240, bcdDevice= 1.00
[   98.634515] usb 4-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[   98.636236] hub 4-1:1.0: USB hub found
[   98.636667] hub 4-1:1.0: 4 ports detected
[   98.730549] usb usb1-port3: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
[   99.698462] usb usb1-port3: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
[   99.698616] usb usb1-port3: unable to enumerate USB device
```

After updating a bunch of firmware and BIOS. Dmesg says:

```
[   49.757738] xhci_hcd 0000:3b:00.0: xHC error in resume, USBSTS 0x401, Reinit
[   49.757756] usb usb3: root hub lost power or was reset
[   49.757763] usb usb4: root hub lost power or was reset
```

Display doesn't show up in Xrandr at all either.
I can't seem to figure out why it won't reconnect after unplugging. A power cycle usually doesn't change anything. I know there are issues with firmware updates bricking thunderbolt, but I don't think this is the case as it does sometimes work.

[This thread mentions something similar](https://community.frame.work/t/linux-12th-gen-external-display-over-usb-c-not-working/21119)